# LINQ check if int? is in List<Int> C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, int

I have object with ID = 5, ID = 6 and List 1,5. Since list has 5 i need to have object with ID = 5 as a result, but if my list has 5 and 6 i need to have both objects as a result. Hope i'm clear enough.

So something like this:

```
result = result.Where(r=>r.ID ***IS IN LIST<int>***).OrderBy(r=>r.ID);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about `list.contains(r.ID)`

Comment: `result.Where(r => list.Contains(r.ID)).OrderBy(r => r.ID)`

Comment: so you want to return elements that exist in both your object and your list?

Comment: The others responds are correct. If you want more complex behaviour with finding something in inner list, this is real-life example what I use :
`Sessions.Where(x => x.Performers.Where(y => y.PerformerId == performerId).FirstOrDefault() != null)`

Comment: Just what i was looking for, nice and easy, couldn't manage to get it myself. Thank you all

Comment: @libik: I would suggest instead ..`.FirstOrDefault() != null` to call `.Any()`

Comment: 3 answers in the same moment.

Answer (score 7):

```
result = result.Where(r=>listOfId.Contains(r.ID)).OrderBy(r=>r.ID);
```

Comment: result = result.Where(r=>listOfId.Contains(r.ID)).OrderBy(r=>r.ID);

Comment: Fixed the missing bracket, thanks @Charkins12

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
result = result.Where(r => somelist.Contains(r.ID)).OrderBy(r => r.ID)
```

Check [List(Of T).Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
 result = result.Where(r=>yourList.Contains(r.ID)).OrderBy(r=>r.ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

something easier to read

```
var results=(from m in MyObjects
            Where myList.Contains(m.Id)
            select m).ToList() ;
```